# AS3 count the number of flashVars before entering if statement

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, for-loop, each, var

I am creating a simple image viewer using AS3 and getting image URLs from flashVars in the HTML. I want to use an if

argument to have it perform one function if there is only one flashVar and another if there are more.

I have it reading the flashVars fine and can write if statments all day long, the trouble I am having is counting the number

of flashVars being passed from the HTML. here is a real dumbed down version of what I am trying to do (which doesnt work

because I can not figure out the correct process to follow):

```
var numberOfVars:Number = 0; // to store the number of flashVars
var paramObj:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters; //get the flashVars

for each (paramObj in LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters){
    numberOfVars + 1;
}

var tf:TextField = new TextField();
addChild(tf);
tf.text = numberOfVars.toString(); // this returns '0' when runningn this code


if (numberOfVars < 2){
    //do this
}

else {
    //do this
}
```

thanks for your help guys.

Chris

Answer (score 4):

You would want to increment numberOfVars

Looks like you have this:

```
 numberOfVars + 1;
```

When you should have this:

```
 numberOfVars++;
```

which is just short way of writing this:

```
 numberOfVars = numberOfVars + 1;
```

or this:

```
 numberOfVars += 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I will offer a slightly different take on the conditional logic here. Instead of reacting to variables *based on how many there are* (introducing plenty of opportunity for unpredictable results) - why not base your conditional statements on what the vars *actually are*. This is my standard flashVar process:

```
var _loadParams:Object
private function init():void 
    {
        _loadParams = new Object();
        _loadParams = LoaderInfo(stage.loaderInfo).parameters;

        someVar     = String(   parseParam( "someVar", "default value") );
    }

    private function parseParam(name:String, defaultValue:String):String
    {
        if (_loadParams.hasOwnProperty(name) && _loadParams[name] != "" && _loadParams[name] != "undefined") 
        {
            return _loadParams[name];
        }
        else
        {   
            return defaultValue;
        }
    }
```

This, obviously, is just testing for the *presence* of a value, but it could be easily altered to call some functionality based on those results:

```
if (_loadParams.hasOwnProperty(name) && _loadParams[name] != "" && _loadParams[name] != "undefined") 
{               
    switch (name){
        case 'param1':
            doSomthing(name);
            break;
        case 'param2':
            doSomthingElse(name);
            break;
    }
}
```

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, and this may be way off. But I thought I'd chime in ;)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `for(key in object)` loop to track the amount of vars stored on `root.loaderInfo.parameters`.

```
var fvars:Object = root.loaderInfo.parameters;

var n:int = 0;
for(var i:String in fvars) n ++;

// n holds the amount of flashvars
if(n <= 1)
{
    // one or no variables found
}
else
{
    // more than one found
}
```

Also, you've done one of your operators wrong:

```
for each(paramObj in LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters)
{
    numberOfVars + 1; // <<<<<< here
}
```

You're looking for one of the following:

```
numberOfVars ++;
numberOfVars += 1;
numberOfVars = numberOfVars + 1;
```